# Merging changes to a folder from another repository

Tags: git, merge

We have a git repository `ProjA` with a plugin stored in `/plugins/foo`.
After this project was completed, a second repository `ProjB` was started. Somewhere along the line foo was added to the repo like so

```
cp ../ProjA/plugins/foo plugins/foo
git add .
git commit -m "Added Foo Plugin"
```

followed immediately by

```
git mv plugins/foo plugins/foobar
git commit -m "Fixed naming conflict with Foo"
```

Then a bunch of work was done.

How do I merge all the changes (and more importantly history) to `ProjB/plugins/foobar` into `ProjA/plugins/foo` without any of the other changes in `ProjB/`?
I've tried creating a subtree and merge it in but all the changes were in `/` and there were no common ancestors to merge with.
Then I tried using `git format-patch` but I couldn't work out how to make it only apply to a subdirectory.
My best guess is to somehow combine the two actions but I don't know how to deal with the paths.

Comment: The easiest way would be using `diff` and `patch` tool. You could also do it with `git diff` but you'd have to modify the paths since you moved your plugin to a different directory. Don't count on commit history though.

Comment: @kaman The commit history is very important to me. If it wasn't, I could just copy the folder back across and commit all the changes in one go

Comment: Yes you could:) In this case i suggest generating patch for each change in this directory using `git format-patch <commit which added your plugin> -- <path to your plugin>` and apply patch one by one to your old repo. you will still have to change each patch manually to fix paths though.

Comment: @kaman I wish I'd seen your comment before I went on my ridiculous subtree adventure - I just checked and that preserves the paths perfectly, even through the rename. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the paths using `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` on `git format-patch`.
There were a few problems involving merges that I had to sort out manually during the 200+ commits imported, but other than that it seems to have worked.

My end workflow was something like this:

```
cd ProjB
git subtree split --prefix=plugins --branch=plugins-only
mkdir ../ProjBPlugins
cd ../ProjBPlugins
git init .
git pull ../ProjB plugins-only
git format-patch --stdout --src-prefix=a/plugins/ --dst-prefix=b/plugins/ e2f0732f92078a83fd210d415b659b41817a865f > foo.patch
cp foo.patch ../ProjA/
cd ../ProjA
git am foo.patch
```